# If $a < b$ and $b = \infty$, then $a < \infty$?

Tags: inequality, infinity

A very simple question, but I am not sure for this moment.

I have a strict inequality $a < b$. And I prove that $b = \infty$, say $b$ is an integral. Does this prove that $a < \infty$, that is, $a$ is finite? Question seems simple but things can easily be messed up with infinity.

To be more clear, say $a = \int f dx$ and $b = \int g dx$ and I have $a < b$. If $\int g dx = \infty$, can we say that $\int f dx < \infty$?

If one can construct pathological counterexamples involve limits etc, I will be very happy.

Comment: If you have **proved** strict inequality, sure. But note that $\int_1^M \frac{1}{2x}\,dx\lt \int_1^M \frac{1}{x}\,dx$ for all $M\gt 1$, but the integrals to infinity of each are "infinite."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talking about $\int fdx$ makes no sense, as that is a concrete function, and not a number.

You might want to talk about the definite integral, $\int_0^\infty fdx$ and $\int_0^\infty gdx$. You may also want to discern between showing $\int_0^\infty fdx<\int_0^\infty gdx$ (in which case your claim would be correct), and the case where $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain over which you are integrating.

In the latter case take $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider for example $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = 2$. Then we have $f(x) <g(x)$ for all $x$ and moreover $$\int_a^b f(x) < \int_a^b g(x)$$ for all finite $a$ and $b$.

But $$\int_0^\infty f(x) = \int_0^\infty g(x) =\infty.$$

Answer (score -1):

This assumption is only correct if $ (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} $.

With $\infty$ in the game, this is no more correct. The concept of $\infty$ has some interesting properties among which is **a lot of fluidness**.

Actually: $\infty \lt \infty$, $\infty /\infty \ne 1$ and bunch of other crazy things are possible with $\infty$.

Comment: If $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$, then $b\in\Bbb R$ and by definition $b<\infty$.

Comment: I mean the assumption: if $ (a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R^3}, a  \lt b \land b = c \Longrightarrow a \lt c $ is only true when $b$ and $c$ are all real. In the case of our the question, we aren't playing with real numbers so, we don't necessarily have $ a \lt \infty $. Do you get it now?